# how to get openstack openrc file through command line

Tags: openstack-horizon

I deployed OpenStack Ubuntu and like to script launch instances. One thing is that I can not find a way to get openrc file other manually log on dashboard and download it.

Is there any way to download this openrc file through command line or api?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am note sure I understood your question correctly. Do you need to chave an openrc script? Because you can create it manually quite easily. If it's the case, you can just follow this link: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-client-environment-scripts.html. If you want to script the launching of instances, you can use the command line, here are the references: http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/. Not sure this was your question but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but I just struggled with this one myself. Note, it's no really the best way since these env seems to change between releases. So abit of a quickfix.

Basic idea is to build the file yourself using the "openstack user show" command.

```
openstack user show <username> | grep id 
| id         | 38107017a45747569461cf7c6ef2cc1f |
| project_id | 808c10c6156c44179f9643c2ac8b0aa3 |
```

Username, password and endpoint's I'm guessing you have a good idea on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are refering to the `stackrc`, if so, you need to connect via ssh to the director (controller) of your openstack and download it manually. Then you need to `source stackrc` and you are good to go to use the `openstack` command on the terminal.